# Rules behind the magic in the Dragonlance world?

Tags: magical-theory, dragonlance

If I remember correctly (it has been quite some years since I've read these, unfortunately), wizards had to memorize the words of a spell to use the spell, and once those words had been uttered, the wizard would forget the words and subsequently need to relearn them if they wanted to use the spell again in the future.

Is this correct? If so, is the reasoning behind that restriction on the magic ever explained? Are there any other set in stone rules for the magic in this universe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The world of Dragonlance is similar to the Forgotten Realms - it's a fantasy setting created for the Dungeons and Dragons roleplaying game. As such, many of  the underlying rules (of magic and otherwise) are drawn from D&D in general, and the Dragonlance campaign setting in particular.

Since Wizards in Dungeons and Dragons largely used Vancian style spellcasting up until 4th edition, I'll refer you to [this excellent answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12310/how-does-dd-vancian-magic-make-sense-in-game) justifying Vancian magic in D&D.

In essence:

> ... during spell preparation, the wizard performs some ritual that "casts" his spells into the ether. He can either "cast" the same spell many times, or spread his allotment out over many spells.
>
> Later, he performs some action (specified by the spell) that triggers the spell. That particular "casting" of the spell is completed, and is no longer available until the wizard is able to prepare it again.
>
> In this way, the spells follow an internally consistent model, without relying on what the wizard should or should not be able to remember.

This description largely applies to Dragonlance as well, though as I recall in that world the ritual inscribes words of magic in the wizard's mind, and saying the final words causes the pent up energy to flare out as a spell.

The wizard hasn't really "forgotten" the words, so much as the words represented a mental construct that caged the energy of the spell; once the spell is cast, the construct is gone.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are. Ingredients! Every spell has to be cast using a preset quantity of often rare or bizare ingredients. The wizard had to carry theese with him and use them up in the process of casting of the spell.
So in essence the wizard is spent mentaly after the casting of a spell and he would not be able to cast a spell if he didnt have the correct ingredients.

As far as i remember this aplies to high level spells mostly. [But here is a list](http://dragonlancenexus.com/lexicon/index.php?title=Spells_of_Krynn) of spells and what you need to cast most of em.

and if memory still serves guano is one of th ingredients in casting of a fireball.
spiderweb/cobweb is needed in using of Web. etc. 
Do not have any refferences but i read many dragonlance/forgotten realms books.

The "War of the Spider Queen" series refferences this more than most as the books focus on a mage more than any other boks apart from the early Dragonlance books about [Raistlin Majere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raistlin_Majere). One of my FAV wizards from Dragonlance, apart from [EL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elminster) (from Forgotten Realms)

Answer (score 2):

One important thing to remember about the original Dragonlance series trilogy is that they didn't start life as books. They actually began life as a campaign setting and a series of 16 modules (12 of them the actual campaign) for that world created for the original Dungeons and Dragons RPG. The original concept came from Tracy Hickman and his wife Laura at the same time that Tracy was joining TSR, the original owners of D&D. The idea was pitched to Gygax. It meshed with an idea he was considering and he had them run with it.

Others were added to the development group, including Margaret Weis, another TSR employee. As is common during development of RPG modules, the group would playtest the module during development. Many of the events of the book were inspired and taken from events that the gamers played out during their playtesting of the modules.

The important part is this. The rules of magic in the original Dragonlance novels are taken directly from the original wizard rules created for Dungeons and Dragons. They did add their own twist to it with the addition of the three moons (white, red, black) in that when a moon that a particular wizard worshiped was waxing, the wizard's powers and abilities were a bit stronger. And when their moon was waning, their powers grew a bit weaker.

But aside from that, the standard D&D rules applied (simplified list of the major rules):

- A wizard must memorize their spells each day
- It must be memorized as many times as they want to cast it (i.e. memorize 3 times, then it can be cast 3 times that day)
- Spells may require one or more casting elements from 3 categories: verbal (speaking the words of the spell), material (having some physical thing to be used as part of the spell), and somatic (making some physical motion with your hands or body to cast the spell)
- Once a spell is cast, it is gone from memory and must be re-memorized
- Spells may only be memorized once per day
- A wizard must rest/sleep for 8 undisturbed hours prior to memorizing their spells
- The more powerful the wizard, the more spells and more powerful spells can be cast

There are many variations, modifications, sub-rules, etc, but those are the high points.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already explained that Dragonlance magic is based upon D&D rules. There are some additional laws of magic especially for the Dragonlance setting which are worth mentioning. @BBlake hints at this with the moons.

1. Magic is linked to the moons - evil mages draw power from the dark moon Nuitari (which no one else can even see), neutral mages from Lunitari (red moon) and good mages from Solinari (white moon). Spells are more powerful if the correct moon is full. There is a special constellation of the moons called the Night of the Eye when all moons are in high sacntion, when magic is even more powerful.
2. The moons are at the same time gods of magic, who work together regardless of their alignment. Their influence in the Dragonlance setting changed over time, in the beginning they were very much in the background and more patron gods of magic instead of having total control of it. In later novels they seem to have the power to deny/grant mortals access to magic altogether.
3. Magic is physically draining. Casting spells exhausts you. This was called Curse of the Magi in one rulebook.
4. Another rule in the early setting was that evil mages get more powerful quickly, but that good mages end up more powerful in the end. This was implemented with XP tables and spell slots. Evil mages gained higher levels more quickly but had less spell slots in the end. This was dropped in later editions.